# RuntimeError at /signup

Tags: python, django

I am beginner in django. I am getting this error:

> You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/signup/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings

Can anyone help me solve this error?

urls of my app:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from home import views


urlpatterns = [
   path('',views.home, name='home'),
   path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
   path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
   path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
   path('signup/', views.handleSignUp, name="handleSignUp"),
]
```

views.py:

```
def contact(request):
    messages.success(request, 'Welcome to contact')
    if request.method=="POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        content = request.POST['content']
        # print(name, email, phone, content)
        if len(name)<2 or len(email)<3 or len(phone)<10 or len(content)<4:
            messages.error(request, "Please fill the form correctly")
        else:
            contact = Contact(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, content=content)
            contact.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your message has been successfully sent")
    return render(request, "home/contact.html")
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
     sno= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
     phone= models.CharField(max_length=13)
     email= models.CharField(max_length=100)
     content= models.TextField()
     timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
          return "Message from " + self.name + ' - ' + self.email
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contact

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Contact)
```

contact.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Contact{% endblock title %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Contact Blog Admin</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="/contact/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="nname">

    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
      <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="content" class="form-label">How may i help you?</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>

    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: use template tag `{% url '<url_name>' %}`

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question more detailed or explicitly than the error message already does.